# Checking for internet in the background

Tags: java, android, database

I would like to be able to run a background process that is always open to check for when the user gets internet.

This is so that when the user comes back online, data I have saved to their phone locally will then automatically push its self to my online database.

I don't know if this is possible without having the app open.

Realm isn't an option due to GDPR

Thank you.

Comment: Make use of `BroadcastReceiver`s and `IntentFilter`s.

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal Will it work whilst the app is closed?

Comment: Also might be worth considering sync functionality that's built into the android framework. See: https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this `BroadcastReceiver` structure:

```
public class InternetReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        //Do Something
    }
}
```

In the `<application>` tag, add:

```
<receiver android:name=".InternetReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: But this wont work unless the user opens the app up right?